# read -a array -d '\n' < foo, exit code 1

Tags: bash, newlines, read

If I try to execute

```
read -a fooArr -d '\n' < bar
```

the exit code is 1 -- even though it accomplishes what I want it to; put each line of `bar` in an element of the array `fooArr` (using bash 4.2.37).

Can someone explain why this is happening

---

I've found other ways to solve this, like the ones below, so that's not what I'm asking for.

```
for ((i=1;; i++)); do
    read "fooArr$i" || break;
done < bar
```

or

```
mapfile -t fooArr < bar
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**What needs to be explained is that the command appeared to work, not its exit code**

`'\n'` is two characters: a backslash <kbd>\</kbd> and a letter <kbd>n</kbd>. What you thought you needed was `$'\n'`, which is a linefeed (but that wouldn't be right either, see below).

The `-d` option does this:

> ```
>   -d delim  continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather
>             than newline
> ```

So without that option, `read` would read up to a newline, split the line into words using the characters in `$IFS` as separators, and put the words into the array. If you specified `-d $'\n'`, setting the line delimiter to a newline, it would do *exactly the same thing*. Setting `-d '\n'` means that it will read up to the first backslash (but, once again, see below), which is the first character in `delim`. Since there is no backslash in your file, the `read` will terminate at the end of file, and:

```
Exit Status:
The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out,
or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.
```

So that's why the exit code is 1.

From the fact that you believe that the command worked, we can conclude that there are no spaces in the file, so that `read`, after reading the entire file in the futile hope of finding a backslash, will split it by whitespace (the default value of `$IFS`), including newlines. So each line (or each word, if a line contains more than one word) gets stashed into the array.

**The mysterious case of the purloined backslash**

Now, how did I know the file didn't contain any backslashes? Because you didn't supply the `-r` flag to `read`:

```
  -r                do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
```

So if you had any backslashes in the file, they would have been stripped, unless you had two of them in a row. And, of course, there is the evidence that `read` had an exit code of 1, which demonstrates that it didn't find a backslash, so there weren't two of them in a row either.

**Takeaways**

Bash wouldn't be bash if there weren't gotchas hiding behind just about every command, and `read` is no exception. Here are a couple:

1. Unless you specify `-r`, `read` will interpret backslash escape sequences. Unless that's actually what you want (which it occasionally is, but only occasionally), you should remember to specify `-r` to avoid having characters disappear in the rare case that there are backslashes in the input.
2. The fact that `read` returns an exit code of 1 does not mean that it failed. It may well have succeeded, except for finding the line terminator. So be careful with a loop like this: `while read -r LINE; do something with LINE; done` 
   because it will fail to `do something` with the last line in the rare case that the last line doesn't have a newline at the end.
3. `read -r LINE` preserves backslashes, but it doesn't preserve leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks! I Thought I had tried the $'\n' approach, but I guess not :/ nice to know about the -r though

Comment: "the rare case that the last line didn't have a newline" does not seem to me to be a compelling reason to advise "never use `while read`". Otherwise, fantastic answer.

Comment: @glennjackman: You can use `while read` as long as you don't have anything inside the loop. Otherwise, it's a bug waiting to bite you -- and believe me, I've been bitten.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. How do you iterate through a file?

Comment: The last line always has a newline. That's how a line is defined: it ends with a newline. If a non-empty file doesn't end with a newline, it isn't a text file, and you can't use text processing tools such as the shell utility `read`.

Comment: @glennjackman: Me, I iterate through columnised files with awk, mostly. For iterating whole lines where the file isn't too big, `mapfile` is pretty cool. For a quick&dirty hack, i'll use the forbidden while loop, but I've stopped putting that in production scripts. YMMV and I softened the warning in the answer.

Comment: Coming back with hindsight: `while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do echo "$line"; done < file` handles files where the last line does not end with a newline.

Answer (score 4):

That is the expected behaviour:

> The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, [...]

```
start cmd:> echo a b c | { read -a testarray; echo $?; }
0

start cmd:> echo -n a b c | { read -a testarray; echo $?; }
1
```